# Auto Inserting Logged In Users Username in Django

Tags: python, django

In the Django Administrative Interface I'd like to Automatically Insert a logged in users username along with a blog post when the publish it, currently I have it displaying every user in a drop down to select from but obviously this is not great so I'd like it to automatically input this.

Here is my code:

models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="published_who")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from django.contrib import admin

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand issue you need to exclude author from admin form:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['author']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

You can overwrite the default behaviour of a ForeignKeyField in the admin with this.
Something along the lines of:

```
  def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
      if db_field.name == "author":
          kwargs["initial"]  = request.user

       return super(PostAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

*This is untested

**EDIT:**

I didn't know whether you wanted to entirely disable the dropdown. With this method you wont. Instead you will have a default value of `request.user` but still be able to select another user.

If you want to make it a drop down with only one selection (weird behaviour :P) you could add:

```
kwargs["queryset"] = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```